# ASIHTTPRequest async updating uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, asihttprequest

I'm using a UITableView which loads data from a server. I need to use async ASIHTTPRequest, which is in a separate .m.

How could I force to reload the table data when the requestFinished:request is called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved with observers although when the app is completely closed won't work. I'll think in something.

Thanks

Comment: Your explanation is not very satisfying. This question is kind of useless now that iOS5 is out.

Answer (score 0):

You can just send the data that needs to be loaded into the TableView by passing it between files. and then finally call a different method of inside the table view that implements the command [self.tableview relaodData];

Update:

What i see from your comments is that the you have a tableView CONtroller or someform of controller that loads the data by calling another class that holds the ASIHTTPrequest/ ansynchrinous requsts. now You have also told me that the TableView Also hold a UIViewController in each cell which i Dont think is a good idea you could go with a custom cell method have a look at this 4 part [tutorial](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/24/table-view-tutorial-part-4-customizing-a-table-cell/)... now and the data that needs to be loaded into the TableView is loaded by TableViewController by some method wither it be each cell or something... so after you are able to get the data just inside the tableViewController just Call the [self.tablebview reloadData] inside the TableViewController which is the parent of the TableView there is no need to call in the other methods.

Comment: Hi megampudi! Thanks. Well, I have an application that calls a uitabview and inside that uitabview I have a uiviewcontroller with the uitableview. How do I call that tableview reloadData from an "external" .m?

Comment: what.... wow... you are having a UITableView inside the UIViewController and that UITableView had a UIViewCOntroller in each cell.

Comment: That's it. An UIViewController with a UITableView. How can I call that's UIViewController reloadData?

Comment: I'm think you are not understanding, sorry. I don't have a "uitableviewcontroller" what I have is a uiviewcontroller that is uitableview's controller. What I don't know how to do is, when the async request gets the response, how to call the tableView reloadData because the requestFinished:request is in a separate .m. I know I can access to the appdelegate with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] but how access to that UIViewController's methods? Thanks!

Comment: i think that is what i said in the first post create a method in the UIViewController and then call it from the Async request finish method... that way there is no problem at alll right.

Comment: I got it, yeah. But the problem is that I don't know how to call that method from an external .m file. That's my doubt! How can I access UIViewController's updateTable method? thanks!